# Google search without the google search bar

Tags: java, android

I'm closing in on the ending stages of my application and ran into an unfamiliar problem. I was able to get a google search bar implemented into my application, however the search bar itself is not needed. When the user makes a selection from pre-selected items listed, I need it to send to google search engine without actually having the search bar on the application. Can anyone give me direction on this matter? Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use can just define the url like this, where X is the search.

```
https://www.google.se/search?q=X
```

Answer (score 0):

Just attach whatever it is you want the user to get search results for to the end of https://www.google.com/#q=

So if you want them to search for "butts", it'd be https://www.google.com/#q=butts

Answer (score 0):

You can just search directly via google REST API.

using something like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures
```

heres more information:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use `EditText` in your activity , then you can implements as `google search` bar , it is all possible by using `Implicit Intent`

**In MainActivity :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);String urlString= editTextID.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, urkString);
startActivity(intent);
```

i hope its helpful for everyone!!!!